# programming with api level 21 in android studio

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I want to write an android app in android studio. I need API level 21 for permissions in install time not in run time, but android studio does not allow to use api level 21. The error is:
Google play requires that apps target API level 26 or higher...
Is there any way i write my program in api level 21 in year 2019!!!?

[error in gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IufDK.png)

Comment: As Google Play says, no, you cannot. It sounds like you're trying to do something shady that they're trying to avoid. You should implement run-time permissions instead.

Comment: I do not want release my app in google play. Is there any way to develop my app permissions in install time?

Answer (score 1):

Set `targetSdkVersion` to 26  & `minSdkVersion` to 21.0 in "`build.gradle`".

Comment: The drawback (if one really only wants to target API 21) is that this may bloat the app with compatibility libraries in order to support API 26 features on an API 21 device.